# Can the "as..as" comparison work in the following way?

Tags: comparison, comparative-constructions

I'm pretty much aware of how to use the "**as..as**" comparison in sentences like:

- The apple is as red as a tomato.
- The car is as old as my grandfather.

etc.

But I was wondering if in complex sentences "**as..as**" can work in the following ways *(whether it is correct)*:

- **As** *many people there live* **as** *many opinions there are*.
- **As** *big a tree can be* **as** *big a house we can build*.

Comment: A many people live there as there are stars in the sky.   I don't know what your second sentence is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Agreed; that second one is as wrong as could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like TRomano said, your first one should go like this:

> *As many people live there **as there are** opinions*.

As for the second one, I can think of a few possibilities, depending on what you are trying to say:

> *That tree **is as big as** any house we could build.*
>
> *We can build a house **as big as** a tree*.
>
> ***As big as** a tree can be, we can build a house just as big*.

(Any of those would be grammatical, but yours is so far off that it's hard to even figure out what you're trying to say.)

Comment: The second sentence is your third example. ))) Thanks.